# Save new file excel with filename cell value

Tags: excel, export-to-excel, vba

I need to generate many .xls files
renamed as the name contained in row A1, A2, A3 ....

example: **NAME1.xls**, **NAME2.xls** ...

and the new generated file must contain only the cells contained in the markers **####**

(see IMG...cellD4:T32)

the markers change manually entered by me.

I tried this code only to save new .xls files
but it does not work....I do not know how to do the rest

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Clickl()
Dim path As String
Dim filename1 As String

path = "C:\"
filename1 = Range("A1").Text
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=path & filename1 & ".xls", FileFormat:=x1OpenXMLWorkbook
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
ActiveWorkbook.Close



End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: This is not a code writing service. Please show what you already have tried, [edit] your question and add your code. People are here to help others to solve issues on their own not to do all the work for them. Reading [ask] might help too.

Comment: @Peh i have edit my question, it's ok?

Comment: x1OpenXMLWorkbook *[sic]* is **not** an XLS format and forcing a .xls file extension does nothing to change that. Google msdn vba saveas and check out the file formats.

Comment: And it must be `xl` not `x1` which is a small `L` not a one!

Comment: pretty sure i got it right with my answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay here ya go. This should grab the chunk of the original workbook you're looking for and save it as multiple new workbooks.

**Option 1** removes formatting

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Clickl()

    Dim wksht As Worksheet
    Set wksht = ActiveSheet

    Dim path As String
    path = "C:\test\"

    If Len(Dir(path, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then
        MkDir path
    End If

    Dim arr() As Variant
    arr = wksht.Range("C3:U33").value

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim i As Long

    For i = 1 To ActiveSheet.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row
        Set wb = Application.Workbooks.Add
        wb.Sheets(1).Range("A1", Cells(UBound(arr), UBound(arr, 2))).value = arr
        wb.SaveAs filename:=path & wksht.Range("A" & i).value & ".xlsx"
        wb.Close
    Next i

End Sub
```

**Option 2** keeps formatting

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Clickl()

    Dim wksht As Worksheet
    Set wksht = ActiveSheet

    Dim path As String
    path = "C:\test\"

    If Len(Dir(path, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then
        MkDir path
    End If

    Dim dataRange As Range
    Set dataRange = wksht.Range("C3", wksht.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell))

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim i As Long

    For i = 1 To wksht.Range("A" & wksht.rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
        Set wb = Application.Workbooks.Add
        dataRange.Copy wb.Sheets(1).Range("A1", wb.Sheets(1).Cells(dataRange.rows.count, dataRange.Columns.count))
        wb.SaveAs filename:=path & wksht.Range("A" & i).value & ".xlsx"
        wb.Close
    Next i

End Sub
```

but note that the starting point is still `C3` based on the example given.

**Option 3** keeps formatting and selects the range between the 2 cells with `####` in them

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Clickl()

    Dim wksht As Worksheet
    Set wksht = ActiveSheet

    Dim path As String
    path = "C:\test\"

    If Len(Dir(path, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then
        MkDir path
    End If

    Dim rngeStart
    Dim rngeEnd

    Set rngeStart = wksht.UsedRange.Find(What:="####", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
    Set rngeEnd = wksht.UsedRange.FindNext(After:=rngeStart)

    Dim dataRange As Range
    Set dataRange = wksht.Range(rngeStart, rngeEnd)

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim i As Long

    For i = 1 To wksht.Range("A" & wksht.rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
        Set wb = Application.Workbooks.Add
        dataRange.Copy wb.Sheets(1).Range("A1", wb.Sheets(1).Cells(dataRange.rows.count, dataRange.Columns.count))
        wb.SaveAs filename:=path & wksht.Range("A" & i).value & ".xlsx"
        wb.Close
    Next i

End Sub
```

**Option 5** keeps row heights and column widths

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Clickl()

    Dim wksht As Worksheet
    Set wksht = ActiveSheet

    Dim path As String
    path = "C:\test\"

    If Len(Dir(path, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then
        MkDir path
    End If

    Dim rngeStart
    Dim rngeEnd

    Set rngeStart = wksht.UsedRange.Find(What:="####", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
    Set rngeEnd = wksht.UsedRange.FindNext(After:=rngeStart)

    Dim dataRange As Range
    Set dataRange = wksht.Range(rngeStart, rngeEnd)

    Dim newDataRange As Range

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long
    Dim k As Long

    For i = 1 To wksht.Range("A" & wksht.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        Set wb = Application.Workbooks.Add
        Set newDataRange = wb.Sheets(1).Range("A1", wb.Sheets(1).Cells(dataRange.Rows.Count, dataRange.Columns.Count))
        dataRange.Copy newDataRange
        For j = 1 To dataRange.Columns.Count
            newDataRange.Cells(1, j).ColumnWidth = dataRange.Cells(1, j).ColumnWidth
        Next j
        For k = 1 To dataRange.Rows.Count
            newDataRange.Cells(k, 1).RowHeight = dataRange.Cells(k, 1).RowHeight
        Next k
        wb.SaveAs filename:=path & wksht.Range("A" & i).Value & ".xlsx"
        wb.Close
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: I did a bit of testing. it seems to work, but if the markers are moved lower ... if I added more lines, it does not work @Marcucciboy2

Comment: ...another problem is that it does not maintain the formatting of cells (colors, sizes and more)

Comment: Question 1: it's because I specified `wksht.Range("C3:U33")` to match the example posted. I can easily make it catch the lowest line in your sheet but without seeing your sheet I can't easily make it match the start if you move it. For question 2, yeah i'll have to change from using arrays to copy and paste. I didnt realize you had special formatting, I was just using the example.

Comment: if your sheet really uses the `####` markers then it would actually be pretty easy

Comment: It's OK now, with the lowest line, but array copy and paste don't keep source coloumn widht and row height.

I have tried also this for export in PDF, but same problem:

`wb.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, filename:=path & wksht.Range("A" & i).Value`

Comment: @pasaico have you tried using the second solution i posted? it no longer uses the array copy and so it will definitely bring your formatting along

Comment: yes, i have used the second solution.

[link]https://wetransfer.com/downloads/ea4b9299e58823a505558e23496fcb9620180111144512/e38c6f example

Comment: Thank for you time but all Option , don't keep source coloumn widht and row height. See example above

Comment: @Marcuccuboy2
you are a genius.
Option 5 is the solution..

THANK YOU

Comment: I'm trying to save everything in PDF format, but it does not work properly

where am I wrong?

`End With
        ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=path & wksht.Range("A" & i).Value & ".pdf", _
        Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False
        ActiveWorkbook.Close
    Next i`

Comment: @pasaico is this a different document you are trying to save? you should open a new question so that i can see all of the code

Comment: it's same document, I would like to try to export to PDF instead of xlsx

Comment: @pasaico please put this into a new question, include your code, and tag me in the comments of it.

Comment: i ask this because it gets messy to solve a new problem in the comments here and because the snippet you added has a `with` statement that i didn't have in my code

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Sub filename()
Dim i As Integer
For i = 1 To 32
    ChDir "C:\path\"
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
        "C:\path\" & Range("A" & i).Value & ".xlsx", _
        FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False
Next i
End Sub
```

Note: Don't use "C:\" choose another folder. Probably you will need admin permissions to save there.